# Google Cloud Vision API could not find a declaration file

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm following this tutorial that uses Ionic framework and Firebase backend to create an image recognition app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taPczl94Eow

For this line:

```
import * as vision from '@google-cloud/vision'
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@google-cloud/vision'. 
'/Users/Private/Workspace/project/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/vision/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/google-cloud__vision` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@google-cloud/vision';`
```

What should I do? I already installed it properly. I also enabled the API from the GCP platform and followed their instructions

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem, so I had to replace this line:

```
import * as vision from '@google-cloud/vision'
```

For this line (it works with Typescript):

```
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
```

I hope this works for your case.